# Azure AD B2C require user to sign in again after the user closes and reopens the Internet Explorer 10 browser - Chrome works well

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I've set up Owin Challange to sign in and sign out the Aad B2c. I've signed in successfully on Internet Explorer, I didn't click the sign out button  to send a logout request to Aad B2c, I just closed the browser then re-open. Now the aad b2c requires me to type username and password again ( the Aad B2c didn't require if I didn't close the browser, and I open a new tab then it worked well). But the problem was it didn't happen on Chrome. So I was confused about which difference Aad B2C deal against between Chrome and IE 10? was perhaps Aad b2c kept the authenticate session on cookies for Chrome, but it kept session in somewhere? it's very helpful if anyone can give me a hint or explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be using IE anymore. Microsoft doesn't support it and it's easily hacked.

Comment: That may well be, but that doesn't answer the question. This is a commentary on the technology.

Comment: Hi @Dave, thanks for your recommendation. There are 20-30% of users using IE on my website, I must to support them. Hope anyone can help me :(